# CodeIgniter and params with square brackets

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have a controller which processes uploads using AJAX.

The controller expects to receive the name of the file as paramater, therefore I need to accept almost any kind of possible character in the URL.

My JavaScript encode the file name using encodeURI(), therefore a file named "*My File [x].avi*" becomes "*My%20file%20%5BX%5D.mpg*". Everything fine so far.

Problem comes when receiving that parameter into CodeIgniter. The URL looks like
http://localhost/myproject/uploader/upload/My%20file%20%5BX%5D.avi

And the header of the controller:

```
function upload($param1='') { }
```

When I print $param1 I got:

```
string(8) "My_file_"
```

Even if I use urldecode() it remains the same. Therefore CodeIgniter is eating the encoded square brackets. Any help?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: any reason you're using (presumably) GET for this rather than POST?

Comment: Because I'm using Valums Ajax Upload ( http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ ), which needs to send the filename as param in the query string.

Comment: Your example is wrong for a start. encodeURI("My File [x].avi") == My%20File%20%5Bx%5D.avi

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's a typo, I'll edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have $config['global_xss_filtering'] set to true and so CI is cleaning the vars.  If this is the case, you can either set it to false or tweak input->xss_clean function.

Comment: Uhm, as far I know the XSS filtering only applies to $_POST and cookies. My $param1 is just part of the query string (it's not even part of $_GET). Thanks for the advice anyway! http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: You need to add more chars (eg : [, %) to this list in config.  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';  And I am not sure anymore what actually is getting stored as file name the original one or the one with special chars.